# php gettext include string with phpcode

Tags: gettext, poedit

i'm trying to use gettext to translate the string in my site

gettext doesn't have problem detecting strings such as

```
<? echo _("Donations"); ?>
```

or

```
<? echo _("Donate to this site");?>
```

but obviously, usually we'll use codes like this in our site

```
<? echo _("$siteName was developed with one thing in mind"); ?>
```

Of course in the website, the $siteName is displayed correctly as

```
   My Website was developed with one thing in mind
```

if we put

```
$siteName = "My Website";
```

previously.

My problem is, i'm using poedit to extract all the strings in my codes that needs to be translated, and it seems poedit doesn't extract all string with php codes like I described above. So how do I get poedit extract strings with php code inside it too? Or is there any other tools I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use `sprintf`. Just make sure you keep the percent (%) in the poedit string!

```
echo sprintf( _("This %s can be translated "), 'string');
```

Or when using multiple variables

```
echo vsprintf( _("This %s can be %s"), ['string', 'translated']);
```

Comment: thank you... never thought php can do this.. seems more like c to me lol